# How to use addField function when the field name is SQL keyword

Tags: 7, database

I have a field with name 'order' in the database. How to select it, using addField?

```
$query->addField('sco_groups', 'order');
```

Gives an error.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Clive SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it, using this code:

```
$query->addField('sco_groups', 'order', 'field_order');
```